# mysql query if condition

Tags: mysql

Hi there i have two tables **a2_deal**(I havent mentioned entire table as its very big)

```
deviceID    companyID   stage       serverTime
1             14          -1         1349449200 
1              1          -1         1349445600 
2             21          -1         1349449200 
3             17          -1         1349447160 
1             14           3         1344449200
1             14           2         1340449200
```

and another table called **a2_comp**

```
companyID   name
1           Microsoft
14          DELL
15          APPLE
17          Google
```

I am trying to get the most recent stage of a company By using below query:

```
SELECT deal.companyID, companies.name as Company,
if(max(serverTime),stage,Null) as Stage
FROM `a2_deal` AS deal
LEFT JOIN `a2_comp` AS companies ON deal.companyID = companies.companyID 
GROUP BY companyID
ORDER BY serverTime
```

in my query i am using **if(max(serverTime),stage,Null) as Stage** which means select the stage value related to most recent server time . ie it should give me -1 as the stage of companyID 14.... But for some reason i am not getting correct output..Please explain how my logic is wrong here... Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT a2_comp.*, a2_deal.*
FROM   a2_deal NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   companyID, MAX(serverTime) AS serverTime
  FROM     a2_deal
  GROUP BY companyID
) t JOIN a2_comp USING (companyID)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dbc8/1/0).

Comment: Ola...Thank You Sir,It worked.... will Natural Join have any performance effenciency over left Join..Just out of curiosity

Comment: @troy: Any performance difference is insignificant. The key differences are that NATURAL JOIN is an inner join whereas LEFT JOIN is an outer join (indeed, they are actually shorthands for NATURAL INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN respectively); also, NATURAL JOIN performs the join on all identically-named columns in both tables, whereas LEFT JOIN requires one to explicitly name the columns/criteria on which the join should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

`case` is used for inline conditions in your query.  Also, you may need to do

`(case when max(serverTime) = serverTime then stage else null end) as Stage`

I'm not totally sure that's valid, but you can try it out.

Comment: In MySQL it's syntactically valid, but produces indeterminate results (the server is free to choose any value from each group for "hidden" columns `serverTime` and `stage`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT deal.companyID, deal.stage, comp.name 
FROM a2_deal AS deal, a2_comp AS comp
WHERE deal.serverTime = 
     (SELECT MAX(deal2.serverTime) 
     FROM a2_deal AS deal2 
     WHERE deal2.companyID = deal.companyID)
AND comp.companyID = deal.companyID
GROUP BY deal.companyID
```

This might be a little confusing but the most interesting part is the sub query which selecting recent serverTime for each company. I have used theta style query and hence JOIN is not necessary.